# Steeltoe upgrade from 2.4.3 to 3.2.6 - break code

Tags: .net-6.0, steeltoe

We are using `Steeltoe.Management.CloudFoundryCore` Version="2.4.3" and trying to upgrade it to Version="3.2.6", however it is breaking while trying to use UseCloudFoundryActuators method something like following.

[image]

By referring the source code, it seems like in latest version the entire `CloudFoundryApplicationBuilderExtensions` class got removed.

Can someone please suggest the alternative solution to use cloud foundryActuators method?

Comment: At this point I would recommend skipping .NET 6 and jumping all the way to 8 (also an LTS) as .NET 6 will be [out of support in 11 months](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)

Comment: Thanks Tim for your kind support, we are planning to upgrade our entire infrastructure whole in a once targeting to .Net8.0 in next year. I need to keep your point in mind upgrading Steeltoe as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Cloud Foundry code was always in the main Endpoints project, so we simplified things a bit and now you can `.AddAllActuators()` [on your hostbuilder](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/welcome/whats-new.html#hostbuilder-extensions) and the Cloud Foundry specifics will light up when running in such an environment.

If you'd prefer to stick with configuring actuators in `startup.cs` you'll want to look at the [source for one of the hostbuilder extensions](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Steeltoe/blob/release/3.2/src/Management/src/EndpointCore/ManagementHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L257) as they contain several lines of code. This particular line of code can be replaced with [`ActivateActuatorEndpoints(this IServiceCollection collection, Action<IEndpointConventionBuilder> configureEndpoints = null)`](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Steeltoe/blob/release/3.2/src/Management/src/EndpointCore/ManagementHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L285)

Comment: In Steeltoe version 3.1, MapAllActuators() doesn't take any parameter, however in latest version 3.2.6 it expects one parameter of type Action<IEndpointConventionBuilder> convention. What should we pass as parameter in it or it is completely optional (can pass null)?

Comment: You can pass null - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71178344/761468

I'll see if I can make that properly optional for 3.2.7